# Mini Aussie as an office dog?

Tags: dogs, pet-selection

I've been thinking of adopting a Mini Australian (or North American) Shepherd. I am gone at work most of the day, but work in a dog-friendly office, so I was thinking that I could take her to work so she doesn't get lonely.

From what I understand, these dogs are smart and non-aggressive, but would spending all day in an office be stimulating enough for them?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the rules for having a dog in the office? Like does the dog have to stay by you while it's there?

Comment: No, they are free to roam around, as long as they aren't jumping on people or barking. It's basically one big open room.

Comment: Do you already have a paticular dog in mind or just a general breed? I own aussies and it really depends on the paticular dog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's a degree of 'it depends' - I can't comment on this specific breed generally.

However - *in general* a tired dog is a happy dog. A dog that is bored/has surplus energy will cause trouble. If they're a clever dog, that might mean a LOT of trouble. (e.g. escaping and going and chasing sheep).

Time in an office is likely to be boring for a dog, but they're *likely* to be content if they've had enough exercise recently. I own quite an energetic dog, who's happiest with 2+ hours of walkies per day.

However, she's fine with a half hour in the morning, followed by a longer walk in the evening, and spends most of the day at home snoozing. She'll ring the bell on the back of the door if she needs to 'go', but otherwise... *mostly* is just fine. (Not that she'd object to being taken out for another hour in the middle of the day).

I don't think it matters too much which dog, but the amount of walkies needed will vary by breed... as will the amount of mischief when they're bored!